# ASP.NET Core 8.0 client-side validation not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, client-side-validation, asp.net-core-8

For some reason, I cannot get the client-side validation to work from my Razor views. However when I created a Razor page by itself without using the Layout page, it works. I'm not sure why. Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Here is the markup and code from my project's `Layout` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DotNetCore8TestSite</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Staging">
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Production">
        <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">DotNetCore8TestSite</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - DotNetCore8TestSite - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    
</body>
</html>
```

And below is the markup in my Razor view:

```
@model DotNetCore8TestSite.Models.ContactForm

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateMessage";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
    // ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = true;

}

<h1>CreateMessage</h1>

<h4>ContactForm</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateMessage" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Message" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Message" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

This is the code from the model class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DotNetCore8TestSite.Models 
{ 
    public class ContactForm 
    { 
        [BindProperty] 
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be blank"), MinLength(3)] 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email cannot be blank"), MinLength(3)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message cannot be blank"), MinLength(5)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the field validators to display the appropriate messages when the fields were validated on hitting the Create Message button, but that's not happening. On the contrary the form is posting back to the server and the Post method is being called.

Strangely, if I create a Razor page without a View and Layout page, using the same class the client-side validation works. So I have figured it has something to do with the Layout page.

Comment: We don't see you project tree. Are you sure your `_Layout.cshtml` file located under `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and not under `~/View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`? Because when I changed the layout file location to `~/View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` the client side validation is working fine for me.

Comment: You wrote: _I was expecting the field validators to display the appropriate messages when the fields were validated on hitting the Create Message button_. This is related to the **Server-Side** validation. The [Client-Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#client-side-validation) validation is performed before you click on the Create button.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes. I have verified the _Layout.cshtml page is under the Pages -> Shared folder. I'm not sure if this is related but where does the _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml file have to be? At present it is under the Views->Shared folder.

When the View is rendered I also right-clicked and viewed the page source and I'm not seeing all the data-val attributes  added to the tags in the html, so definitely the jquery is not working for some reason.

Comment: If your project is ASP.NET Core MVC the location should be `~/View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. When your project is ASP.NET Razor Pages the location should be `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. The `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` should be located under the `/View/Shared` folder if the project is using the  ASP.NET Core MVC  template. It the question above you are noted the your project is `asp.net-core-mvc`. If so, just use `~/View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` NOT `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: See [MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/develop-asp-net-core-mvc-apps#mvc-and-razor-pages)

Comment: Thanks again. You brought out a very important point. Initially I wanted to keep the project simple and wanted to just use Razor pages. But then later realized it would be better to use MVC for this part and so switched to MVC. I made a copy of the _Layout.chstml which was under the Pages -> Shared folder and moved it to the Views -> Shared folder and changed the path in the View to point to that Layout page. However it's still not working and the Client Side validation is not firing.

Comment: Hi Jackdaw, I finally figured it out. Besides copying the _Layout.cshtml to the Views -> Shared folder, I also had to copy the _ViewImports.cshtml and the _ViewStart.cshtml to the Views main folder. Now everything is working. Thank you so much for helping me out with this. Have a wonderful day...:-)

Comment: Well, you can post below your solution as the answer. Perhaps it will help someone...